# C++ Drop Sub-range from the middle of a range

Tags: c++, vector, c++20, std-ranges

I have a container (`std::vector`), and I'd like to check if any of its elements satisfy a predicate, to do that I use C++20's `std::ranges::any_of`.

The problem is, I'd like this `any_of` to skip cetain elements in the middle of the range (a sub-range with known offset and size). How can I "drop" those elements from the range before it goes into the `any_of` algorithm, while also not completely erasing them?

What I could think of is to use `views::take` and `views::drop` to get only the elements outside the subrange, then combining those into a new vector and `views::join`ing it. But this seems rather inefficient, and definitely not very clean.
What would be a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: Just make two tanges and check them separately.

Comment: Any reason you need to use ranges just to check the elements of a vector?

Comment: I did not think about checking the two separately, it's definitely an improvement over my idea.
and the reason I use ranges is mostly for learning purposes, but also they seem a lot more convenient & safe than iterator pairs in general, so I don't see a reason to not use them.

Comment: @aradarbel10 You can create two [`subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange)s and use range-v3's [`views::concat`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/test/view/concat.cpp) to combine them into one single range, then pass it to your `ranges::all_of`.